Facing SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) when querying using MGET command using Jedis (Java Redis Client)
I have a use case to identify expired tokens stored in cache, so I implemented a method in the following way -
private Boolean isTokenExpired(long programId,String token,Jwt jwt){
    try {
        if(!jedis.isConnected() || generalConfigHelper.getInt(REDIS_DB_INDEX) != jedis.getDB()){
           jedis=redisHelper.getConnection();
           jedis.select(generalConfigHelper.getInt(REDIS_DB_INDEX));
        }
        Claims claims = (Claims) jwt.getBody();
        //redis keys
        String tokenCacheKey=programId+":Tokens:"+token;
        String expiryTimeKey=programId+":InvalidateTokensBefore:"+claims.get("user_id");
        List<String> values=jedis.mget(tokenCacheKey,expiryTimeKey);
        if (values.get(0)!=null){
            return true;
        }else if (values.get(1)!=null){
            log.info("redis: exp value:"+values.get(1));
            long exp=Long.parseLong(claims.get("exp_ms")+"");
            return exp<Long.parseLong(values.get(1)+"");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        log.info("Error while reading from redis:"+ex);

    } finally {
        log.debug("Returning jedis instance to the pool");
        redisHelper.closeConnection(jedis);
    }
    return false;
}


The above code intially checks if client is connected to the resource pool and proceeds with select and mget commands, during the execution of these following commands I'm facing the following exceptions - SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) and SocketException: Socket is closed.
My Jedis Pool Configuration -
maxTotal - 512
maxIdle - 32
minIdle - 8
timeout - 10000 ms
Upon researching about these exceptions I found these GitHub issues which were highlighting these exceptions -
https://github.com/mozilla/gcp-ingestion/issues/451
https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues/185
The issues highlight about how the Redis Client timesout and breaks the connection therefore resulting in the following issues and made some recommendations for the timeout, I have followed the recommended config and still seem to face issues.

Which recommended config did you follow?

May I suggest to have a redisHelper.getConnectionPool() and not use a global jedis variable?
private Boolean isTokenExpired(long programId, String token, Jwt jwt) {
    try (Jedis jedis = redisHelper.getConnectionPool()) {
        jedis.select(generalConfigHelper.getInt(REDIS_DB_INDEX));
        ...
        ...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info("Error while reading from redis:", ex); // not sure which logger
                // you're using but you should use this option if possible
    }
    return false;
}

